# Building dynamic Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I use dynamically built regex. Problem is when `symbol = "aaaa (1)"` because regex tries to parse it, but I want to treat it literary

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(^" + "/(" + symbol + @" \(\d+\)$)|" + symbol);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to escape special chars:

```
var escapedSymbol = Regex.Escape(symbol);
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(^" + "/(" + escapedSymbol  + @" \(\d+\)$)|" + escapedSymbol );
```

Reffer: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)